# How to select parent of parent component by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

And is there a way to get to parent of parent of parent? :) Not to make it this way:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'folder name')]").find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath('//tr[2]/td[2]/div')
```

So I need to find at first my folder name, than go to parents and only than find my element. It is the only way I can made it. Because all folders have the same elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express it as a single xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[contains(text(), 'folder name')]/../../..//tr[2]/td[2]/div"
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), \'test folder\')]/../../..//tr[2]/td[2]/div"}' ;

Comment: @Michael, Could you show me the html/url you're handling?

Comment: But it works this way: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'folder  name')]").find_element_by_xpath("//../../..//tr[2]/td[2]/div")

Comment: OK.. I get path that I need. //*[contains(text(), 'test folder')]/../../../../td[2]/div

Comment: You have one extra slash before tr[2]. This can be an error. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @Michael, I rejected your edit because that make my answer invalid (make it different xpath from the xpath in the question). Two slash can be in the middle of xpath; meaning finding in descendants, not only in children.

Comment: I add HTML to my question. So you can see I found folder, that goes 3 times to parent and then go to my direction. So with 2 slashes I can go only to 2 parent and than use "//" in the middle?

Comment: @Michael, Could you provide more complete html? It has only one `tr`. Anyway I changed the answer to not include `//` in the middle. (BTW, my code works as I commented in the previous comment, http://pastebin.com/UWkhgVT4, html: http://fiddle.jshell.net/falsetru/97zczw33/show/)

Comment: Sorry... It works with 2 slashes too. The problem now was that our developers already change HTML, and I have to delete tr[2]... That was the problem. You ware right.

Comment: @Michael, rolled back the answer accordingly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your expression shorter by using `ancestor` xpath function. See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp as an example. For your case it would look like `//*[contains(text(), 'folder name')]/ancestor::/div` (it probably needs to be corrected because there is no exact snippet of HTML provided in the question).